# Python 3 getattr string to name why is it bad?

Tags: python, qt

I have a string : `

("Bit" + str(loopCount) ))`

loopcount is just a number that I increment in a loop.

What I want to do with that is creating some qtwidget as such :

```
self.Bit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
self.Bit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
self.Bit3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
```

...and so on as many as I have in LoopCount.

To do so I need to convert my string as a name. By looking on the net I have found this getattr which seems from far the easiest way to do so :
    for BitNmb in range(0, self.mySpnValue):
    getattr(self, ("Bit" + str(loopCount) ))

which give me this error :
AttributeError: 'Class2' object has no attribute 'Bit1'
Which is quite frustrating as I can see in the error I obtain what I want with the "Bit1" but I have not a clue why it want to be a attribut of my class.
And no way to do simply

```
getattr(self, ("Bit" + str(loopCount) )) = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

error : SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I have read many time "do not use getattr us a dictionary" ok... but why ? Using a dictionary sound like a lot of work just for doing such a simple thing ?

Thanks

Comment: `setattr` does what you're trying to do.  But really, just use a list: `self.bits = [QtGui.QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(loop_count)]`

Comment: And I just understood why I get this error, it's because of "self"... arg.
Thanks for the list exemple but I really don't understand it, I am not especially new in coding but self.bits = [QtGui.QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(loop_count)] dosen't make a lot of sens to me. If I am doing something like that I will find myself having several identical self.bits which don't even seem possible. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than create separate, numbered attributes, use a list or dictionary. In this case, a list will do just fine:

```
self.bits = [QtGui.QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(3)]
```

creates a list of 3 `QLineEdit` objects.

To *set* attributes dynamically, you'd use the [`setattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(self, 'Bit{}'.format(loopCount), QtGui.QLineEdit(self))
```

Comment: But something goes wrong when I then want to use the list :
 for BitNmb in range(0, self.mySpnValue):
self.vbox2.addWidget(self.bits[loopCount]-1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'QLineEdit' and 'int'

So I have looked closer and here's what contain my list : <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0x00000000030C3F78>
that's my Gui yes but not selfBits1...
 self.vbox2.addWidget(setattr(self, 'Bit{}'.format(loopCount), QtGui.QLineEdit(self)))  return me another error :
QLayout: Cannot add null widget to QVBoxLayout/

I am quite a bit lost with this list method,why using getattr so bad ?

Comment: You are trying to subtract 1 from your `QLineEdit` object: `self.bits[loopCount]-1`. Perhaps you wanted to put that `- 1` *inside* the indexing expression?

Comment: Ho dear... shame on me, thank you very much for your help everything is working fine and all nice and tidy : ) Thanks !